# auth()->user() returns unexpected user and different user

Tags: laravel

Why does auth()->user() returns different logged in user?

Tried debugging it..

```php
dd(auth()->user())
```

I'm using `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in my LoginController

Comment: What is it returning? Are they the same model? Same guard? (e.g. `Auth::guard('api')->user()` might be different to `Auth::user()`)

Answer (score 0):

use
`dd(Auth::user());`  and if u want any particular field data
use

```
dd(Auth::user()->field_name);
```